# Replace string inside delimiters in java regular expression without \K

Tags: java, json, regex, string

I have a JSON that looks like this:

```
{"firstName":"Gabriela","id":9153,"language":"en","lastName":"Manriquez","login":"gmanriquez_training","profileCodes":"[role1","role2","role3","role4","role5 ]","status":"A","statusName":"Active"}
```

I want to extract the " from inside the [ delimiters, this is the spected result:

```
{"firstName":"Gabriela","id":9153,"language":"en","lastName":"Manriquez","login":"gmanriquez_training","profileCodes":"[role1,role2,role3,role4,role5]","status":"A","statusName":"Active"}
```

I've tried this regular expression:

```
(?i)(?:\G(?!\A)|profileCodes\"\:\s*\")[^\]"]*\K\"
```

But the \K is not supported in the engine where i want to implement it, cause the flag is not avaliable for java.

Is there any way to obtain the same result without using \K?

Comment: `(?i)(\G(?!\A)|profileCodes\"\:\s*\")([^\]"]*)\"` -> `"$1$2<NEWVAL>"`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't need `\K` if you work with capturing groups:

```
(\[|\G(?!\A))([^]"]*)"

 ^^^^^^^^^^^  ^^^^^^
      $1        $2
```

and replace with `$1$2`.

See [live demo here](https://regex101.com/r/fMy6eD/1)

You could also use a lookbehind in place of first capturing group above:

```
(?<=\[|\G(?!\A))([^]"]*)"
```

and replace it with just `$1`.

See [live demo here](https://regex101.com/r/tiWErm/1)

Comment: Worked out! Thanks a lot!